# What Rails cms supports custom template container?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, refinerycms

I am trying to differentiate all different kinds of cms for rails. But, my main criteria is to create template containers.

For example. Lets say Im creating a website for AMC theaters. I want to create a container with multiple pages in this form:

```
Theater home page
   └ Hours and contact info
   └ movies list
   └ specials
       └ Kids and 65+ discounts
       └ seasonal specials
       └ bundle deals
   └ Dining
   └ Directions
```

Thats what the layout would look like. I want to create a universal theater template that has all those pages so I can create multiple theater pages. Is it possible to do it through Refinery or Browser cms?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what approach is more suitable for you but ComfortableMexicanSofa can do things like that: https://github.com/comfy/comfortable-mexican-sofa

Take a look at the wiki specifically mirroring functionality.